# Composer update throws error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Helllo,

When I try to update my project with `composer update` I receive this error:

```
> php artisan clear-compiled


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  parse error                                              


Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:
```

When I try this:

```
composer update --no-scripts


Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

It succeeds?

What could be wrong here?

**--EDIT--**

```
install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: what is error output?

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  parse error                                              


Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:

Comment: Anything after  Error Output: ?? ALso the version of your laravel

Comment: Please see my edit. I use Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move php artisan clear-compiled from "pre-update-cmd" to the "post-update-cmd" in your composer.json file

```
"post-update-cmd": [
  "php artisan clear-compiled",
  "php artisan optimize"
]
```

Comment: The error is caused because there was a change made to how composer works. More details https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5066#issuecomment-196979820